# Does BitTorrent work in the background after quitting qBitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

Recently I installed qBitTorrent so I could download some episodes of a Creative Commons-licensed TV series. I simply used `apt-get install qbittorrent`, ran `qbittorrent`, then added the torrent files, and pressed "start". I noticed that the series would take too long to download, so I quit qBitTorrent when it was at 10%. The next day, I launched qBitTorrent again, and was surprised to find the downloads complete. Either the 2.5 GBs downloaded within 3 seconds or something else occurred.

Does BitTorrent continue to exchange files after starting the download in qBitTorrent and then quitting qBitTorrent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

qBitTorrent has a mode where it is minimized in the notification area. If you go to the Options, then in the Behaviour tab, you will see a tree of checkboxes reading "Show qBit in notification area", and "Close qBit to notification area". This is the only way for qBittorrent to keep operating if you click the close button.

Comment: Those checkboxes are greyed out. Using gnome.

Answer (score 3):

I use qBittorrent, and to the best of my knowledge, that is not the case. When the qBittorrent GUI is not running, it is not engaging in any sneaky file uploads and downloads behind your back. If it did, frankly, that would be a bit bananas, and violate the principle of least surprise along with just plain normal, ordinary, common-sensical user expectation.

You can easily run something that tracks network activity. `iftop` comes to mind. That should show you if anything is going on. It is possible that the behavior of qBittorrent has changed dramatically since the version I am using.
I hope not, but it is always possible for developers to go insane.

What version are you using? I'm using `3.0.9-1` on Debian wheezy (stable), originally backported from unstable, but currently not corresponding to any version of qBittorrent on any Debian mirror.

I see the current version in unstable is `3.1.9.2-1`. Perhaps I should give that a whirl, though `3.0.9-1` is currently working fine for me.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily thinking qBitTorrent was doing the downloading, but maybe bittorrent itself was told to run by qBitTorrent, and bittorrent kept running in the background.

Comment: I don't think there is a separate bittorrent application that runs in the background, at least I have never seen signs of such a thing. Do you have reason to believe this is the case? The bittorrent functionality is integrated into bittorrent. I can believe that what may have happened is that you exited the GUI, but qbittorrent kept on running (possibly in some sort of *stuck* state) and carried on downloading. I've seen this kind of thing happen with other GUI applications, but I cannot remember if I have seen it with bittorrent.

Comment: You could also check `iotop`. This would show if an application is writing to disk. "bittorrent itself was told to run by qBitTorrent". If there was a separate client that was called by qBittorrent, it would be a dependency of the Debian qBittorrent Debian package. There is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Qbittorrent on windows and most definitely after I quit it remains active, but there is no trace of it on the desktop except among the running processes in Win 10.
I don't run it on Linux, so I don't know the difference between the two, but on Windows 10 Qbittorrent never really quits. I have to restart to make sure it's not in the background.
Additionally, it doesn't seem to respond to a Force Quit either. It just sits there, consuming 0% CPU like a ghost.